# mysql server start failed

Tags: server, startup, mysql

I am running ubuntu server.
When I tried to login to mysql(which was running),I got the following error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket         '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

But mysqld.sock file doesn't exist inside `/var/run/mysqld` folder.
On executing `ps aux | grep mysql` command,I realized that mysql server was not running.

I then tried to restart mysql server using

```
service mysql start
service mysql restart
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

But,the start process failed in all 3 cases.
`/var/log/mysql/mysql.log` and `/var/log/mysql/mysql.err` files are empty.

But `/var/log/error.log` shows following information:

```
140425 12:49:05 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140425 12:49:05 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140425 12:49:05 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140425 12:49:05 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140425 12:49:05 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
140425 12:49:05 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140425 12:49:05 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 3.0G
140425 12:49:05 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 5242880 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 26214400 bytes!
140425 12:49:05 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140425 12:49:05 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140425 12:49:05 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'record_buffer=64M'
140425 12:49:05 [ERROR] Aborting

140425 12:49:05 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: see if this helps: http://serverfault.com/questions/104014/innodb-error-log-file-ib-logfile0-is-of-different-size

Comment: What is the output of `ls /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*`?

Comment: ls: cannot access /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*: No such file or directory

Comment: Is your /var/lib/mysql directory writable for mysql?

Comment: I am a linux newbie..I changed the permissions of /var/lib/mysql by using chmod 777 *.*  Can you please suggest me how to check if this is not the right way?

Comment: @Jobin : sudo find / -name 'ib_logfile0' gave output /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0..(if i don't use sudo it says permission denied).I got same outputfor ib_logfile1 too..

Comment: Fix for me:
```sudo mkdir /var/log/mysql && sudo mkdir /var/mysqld && sudo chown -R mysql /var/mysqld/ && sudo chown -R mysql /var/log/mysql```

Answer (score 33):

Open a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and do the following:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo rm /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0
sudo rm /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1
```

and comment out the line `record_buffer=64M` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` <sup>[[1]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455029/mysql-server-start-failed/455062#comment598401_455062)</sup>

and then restart msyql using:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

[(Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20141146/1317271)

Comment: I ran the commands you mentioned..On running sudo service mysql restart, it gave a message stop: Unknown instance and shell prompt didn't appear(restart is still running from past 50 mins)

Comment: Also, now the error log says:                                            -140425 15:09:11 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140425 15:09:12  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140425 15:09:13 InnoDB: 5.5.37 started; log sequence number 940942258188
140425 15:09:13 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'record_buffer=64M'
140425 15:09:13 [ERROR] Aborting

140425 15:09:13  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
140425 15:09:14  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 940942258188
140425 15:09:14 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

Comment: No..I did sudo service mysql restart.

Comment: Can you try doing `sudo service mysql start`?

Comment: Should I kill the mysql restart process which is running? Will it cause any problem??

Comment: Yes, you can kill the process, it should be harmless.

Comment: @user1985948: Was the issue resolved?

Comment: I did sudo service mysql stop.                                     Then I did sudo service mysql start.                                         -The process is still running(bash prompt did not appear) from 15 minutes..I did not get any message as in the previous case.

Comment: Do the log files have anything?

Comment: The tail of /var/log/mysql/error.log is                            `-140425 15:52:18  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140425 15:52:19 InnoDB: 5.5.37 started; log sequence number 940942258188
140425 15:52:19 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'record_buffer=64M'
140425 15:52:19 [ERROR] Aborting

140425 15:52:19  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
140425 15:52:20  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 940942258188
140425 15:52:20 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete`

Comment: It worked when I commented a line `record_buffer=64M` in /etc/mysql/my.cnf file..Thank you very much.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23: It is actually he himself who solved it and later I updated my question for people who come at this post later.

Comment: I just removed the log files without the memory change and it worked :S :S :S

Comment: Killing the two log files and restarting worked for me

Answer (score 9):

I solved the problem in the following way:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
mysql_install_db --user=mysql -ldata=/var/lib/mysql/
```

In another context, I faced it because the **mysql daemon** failed to start. So start daemon with command - `mysqld start` and then try to start the service.

Answer (score 9):

This solved my problem:

`mkdir /var/run/mysqld`

`touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

`chown -R mysql /var/run/mysqld`

`/etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Comment: after applying these steps my database is got deleted. Now what will I do??

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message and the same emptyness in the log files. In my config-file (my.cnf) I had specified that I wanted to use myisam tables, by adding this line in the [mysqld]-section:

```
default-table-type = myisam
```

After upgrading mysql it seems this causes mysql not to start. I have changed this to:

```
default-storage-engine = myisam
```

and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the available RAM by adding new Swap space might also help. Steps are [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Make sure that you create /swapfile of the size smaller than the available space shown by

```
df -h
```

For example for me output of df- h was:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  1.2G  6.3G  16% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            492M   12K  492M   1% /dev
tmpfs           100M  336K   99M   1% /run
```

So I created using 2 G

```
sudo fallocate -l 2G /swapfile
```

And then just start the service

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Hope this helps. All the best.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error, and last 2 times I had to delete and reinstall mysql server as I didn't have much data there.

But, the error used to happen consistently for me, when I used stacer to clean my cache files.

**It actually deletes the `var/log/mysql/error.log` path. Along with the `mysql` directory.**

To fix that, I created the directory manually,

```bsh
sudo mkdir /var/log/mysql
sudo touch /var/log/mysql/error.log
sudo chown -R mysql: /var/log/mysql
```

**And then restart using:**

```
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

- The error previously it was showing on `sudo systemctl status mysql`

`Error: 2 (No such file or directory)`

- After I have created the directory but not
  `sudo chown -R mysql: /var/log/mysql`

`Error: 13 (Permission denied)`

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

Check if in all /etc/rc1.d ... /etc/rc5.d the mysql script starts with S (Ex S10mysql) and not K AS K10mysql.

Explanation: K prefix loads with stop, kind of kill service; and S prefix starts with start parameter.

```
execute in terminal:   
(command        script action  runlevel)
---------------------------------------
sudo update-rc.d mysql enable  2
sudo update-rc.d mysql enable  3
sudo update-rc.d mysql enable  4
sudo update-rc.d mysql enable  5
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was a space issue.
Check if you have enough space left.

from `/var/log/mysql/error.log` I got some hints from two lines:

```
2018-08-04T05:25:29.519139Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Write to file ./ibtmp1failed at offset 3145728, 1048576 bytes should have been written, only 704512 were writt$
2018-08-04T05:25:29.519145Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Error number 28 means 'No space left on device'
```

I could see that it is a space issue.

```
root@xxx:/home/user1# df -h
Filesystem                            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                  477M     0  477M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                 100M   11M   89M  11% /run
/dev/mapper/server1--osticket--vg-root  8.3G  7.9G     0 100% /
tmpfs                                 497M     0  497M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                 5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                 497M     0  497M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda1                             472M  467M     0 100% /boot
tmpfs                                 100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
```

From here, I could see that there was not enough space left on the virtual server `/dev/mapper/server1--osticket--vg-root  8.3G  7.9G     0 100% /`. And I thought on either migrating or increasing the virtual drive, but I decided to remove unnecessary files first.

So, had to clean up cache and files that were not needed:

```
#apt-get clean
#apt-get -f autoremove
```

Then, do not forget to remove the mysql corrupted log files afterwards. They would be generated again when you restart mysql

```
#service mysql stop
#cd /var/lib/mysql
#rm ib_logfile*
#service mysql start
```

Check your mysql server service and it is probably up and running

```
root@server1-osticket:/var/lib/mysql# service mysql status
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-08-04 23:07:24 WAT; 7min ago
  Process: 1559 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1549 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1558 (mysqld)
    Tasks: 29
   Memory: 280.3M
      CPU: 589ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─1558 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Aug 04 23:07:19 server1-osticket systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Aug 04 23:07:24 server1-osticket systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
root@server1-osticket:/var/lib/mysql#
```

Case closed.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the file /var/lib/mysql/.run-mysql_upgrade and it should start

;)

**"With great power comes great responsibility"**

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I set `max_allowed_packet = 0.5M` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

I solved it by changing `max_allowed_packet` to `1M`.

Answer (score 0):

The following command resolve my issue and mysql could start after it.(it might to useful in some cases)

```
chown -R mysql: /var/lib/mysql
```