# Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found

Tags: mysql, xampp

Today Xampp suddenly stopped working.

When I try to start xampp, then mysql is not running:

[image]

After browsing for this issue, I found that

> sudo service mysql start

should solve it. However, this casuses the error mentioned in the subject line:

> Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.

What happend and how to fix it? I tried to restart my device but the problem remains.

Comment: [mysql server start failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455029/mysql-server-start-failed/697295#697295) may help.

Comment: Have you tried launching GUI of XAMPP and starting it from there?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo service mysql start
```

This command starts the daemon of mysql if the script to start the daemon is in /etc/init.d
But you installed mysql by xampp. 
So I think it is not there.
Please find and invoke the daemon.

Comment: is it not `sudo systemctl mysql start` now?  or maybe mysqld?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537851/difference-between-systemctl-and-service-command#:~:text=service%20operates%20on%20the%20files,file%20in%20%2Fetc%2Finit.